# Javascript async promises as macrotasks

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise, async-await

In my application at some point I queue so many microtasks through promises that the UI gets blocked and becomes unresponsive.

Is there any way I can queue them as macrotasks in a similar way?
Using setTimeout() works fine, the UI becomes responsive again, but the code is just horrendously ugly and gets me into callback hell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We'd have to see your actual code to know what to suggest.  If you're queuing that many promises, there's probably a better way to write your code.  Promise themselves don't allow configuring how their task scheduling works.  You could probably get a 3rd party Promise library that uses a different task scheduling method, but honestly that isn't really  the proper way to solve your problem.  You probably need to manage the number of asynchronous operations you have in flight at once so you don't overwhelm the UI responsiveness or use webWorkers to do some of the work,

Comment: We can only help with the proper way of fixing this problem if you share your actual code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I have to draw a huge graph (not like plotting a function, but a graph theory graph) from some data. While the graph is being drawn I want to show some sort of progress report (eg progress bar). The code is rather huge and invlovles librairies etc, thought it would be too much code and too specific to post here. Right now for every node that has to be added there is a dedicated asynchronous task. After all nodes have been added, the edges are added similarly. If everything is done "at once" (synchronously) the browser freezes for some time. Thx for responding

Comment: Random guess since it's pretty hard to follow without seeing some relevant code, but can you inject tiny delays in your promise chain with `setTimeout()` to inject more opportunities for the UI to process things?  `function delay(t, v) {return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t, v))}` is a function I use for adding a delay to a promise chain.  Or you can wrap that `function insertDelay(t) {return function(v) { return delay(t, v);}}` so you can then do `somePromise().then(insertDelay(5)).then(...)` anywhere in the promise chain.

Comment: Or, slow down the rate at which you launch all these asynchronous operations so there aren't so many going at once?  Or find a way to combine multiple requests into one asynchronous operation so there aren't so many in total?  Or, make the processing of each asynchronous operation more efficient.  Or move some processing to webWorkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are queuing enough promises to starve the UI because promises run at a higher priority than many other types of events, then you are probably just trying to run too many asynchronous operations at once or have written the code in a way that creates far too many promises that have to be scheduled and compete with other things.

The proper way to fix this is probably to fix your code so it's not trying to create that many promises.  We can only help you with that if you show us the code that is actually causing that problem.

> Is there any way I can queue them as macrotasks in a similar way?

The promise implementation built-into JS does not make it configurable how promises are scheduled so they are hard-wired to use their micro tasks that are higher priority than many other things in the event queue and you cannot change that.

You could get a third party library (one that was built for promise use before JS has promises built-in) that did not have access to the microtask system and would have used something like `setTimeout()` or `setImmediate()`. But, you'd have to somehow make sure all your code was switching to this 3rd party library and not inadvertently using the built-in implementation.

Honestly that feels like a total hack and is not a solution I would pursue.  The single threaded JS is a cooperative system.  To keep a UI responsive, it relies on some cooperation and not hammering the main thread with high priority or long running operations in order to keep a UI responsive.

In some cases, you can move some code out to a webWorker (if this is a browser) or a WorkerThread if this is node.js and get the troublesome code out of the same event loop as the UI.

But, the best solution is probably to tame your promise-driven code so it's not running so many promise-scheduled things in a row that it interferes with the UI.  We can only help with some ideas on how to do that if you show us the promise code that is actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you create a promise, the promise will execute. Therefore, the promises creations need to be queued up. One of the best packages to perform these sort of operations is called [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async). It has 26.2K stars in Github at the time of writing.

Check out the [queue example](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) in their docs to get a better feeling for how it works:

```js
// create a queue object with concurrency 2
var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
    console.log('hello ' + task.name);
    callback();
}, 2);

// assign a callback
q.drain(function() {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
});
// or await the end
await q.drain()

// assign an error callback
q.error(function(err, task) {
    console.error('task experienced an error');
});

// add some items to the queue
q.push({name: 'foo'}, function(err) {
    console.log('finished processing foo');
});
// callback is optional
q.push({name: 'bar'});

// add some items to the queue (batch-wise)
q.push([{name: 'baz'},{name: 'bay'},{name: 'bax'}], function(err) {
    console.log('finished processing item');
});

// add some items to the front of the queue
q.unshift({name: 'bar'}, function (err) {
    console.log('finished processing bar');
});
```

Comment: Without more info from the OP, this seems like a bit of a guess as to what the actual problem is.